# HttpURLConnection request being hit twice to the server for downloading file

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

Following is my android code for downloading file from sever.

```
private String executeMultipart_download(String uri, String filepath)
            throws SocketTimeoutException, IOException {
        int count;
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        // uri="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTzoeDGx78aM1InBnPLNb1209jyc2Ck0cRG9x113SalI9FsPiMXyrts4fdU";
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
        Log.d("File Download", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
        httpStatus = connection.getResponseCode();
        String statusMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
        connection.disconnect();
        return statusMessage;
    }
```

I have debugged this code. This function is called only once even if it hits server twice. 
Is their any error in this code.

Thanks

Comment: Try to find out which requests arrive at the server. I suspect one request is for the file download, the other might request the ``favicon`` or some other non-related stuff.

Comment: Both request are same.

Comment: @RahulGiradkar I've added answer, please, check it

Comment: `connection.connect()` is redundant, and you should get the response code before doing anything else with `connection`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your error lies in this line:

```
url.openStream()
```

If we go to grepcode to sources of this function, then we will see:

```
public final InputStream openStream() throws java.io.IOException {
    return openConnection().getInputStream();
}
```

But you already opened connection, so you opening connection twice.

As solution you need to replace `url.openStream()` with `connection.getInputStream()`

Thus your snipped will looks like:

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
    Log.d("File Download", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
```