# URLConnection hits server twice when downloading file?

Tags: android, django, httpurlconnection

After reading this related issue: [HttpURLConnection request being hit twice to the server for downloading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583020/httpurlconnection-request-being-hit-twice-to-the-server-for-downloading-file) I made sure to use `urlConnection.getInputStream()` instead of `url.openStream()`, but I still see my server gets two requests for a single download.

This is the AsyncTask I use to download a file from my Django web server:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
    String path = "/sdcard/YourApp.apk";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Token " + authToken);            
        urlConnection.connect();

        int fileLength = urlConnection.getContentLength();

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());//url.openStream());

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(path);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            //publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();

        urlConnection.disconnect();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SVC0", e.getMessage());
    }

    return path;
}
```

Then I look at the Django logs and I can see that two requests are present:

```
[09/Oct/2019 02:30:29] "GET /update HTTP/1.1" 301 0 
[09/Oct/2019 02:30:35] "GET /update/ HTTP/1.1" 200 19451876
```

I am using Android 5.1.1 and I have tried commenting out many parts of the above function to isolate the issue but I just can't figure out why it's causing the multiple requests and that 301 error.

Any help tracking this 'bug' down would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why are you calling `urlConnection.connect();` ?

Comment: I copied it from another example. But I was wondering myself so I did try commenting out that line, but nothing changed and still was seeing multiple requests.

Comment: Adding a forward slash to the end of the URL was the solution in my case. Not exactly sure why.